# iOS app hangs when tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My app occasional hangs when opening/awakening from the background. I'll tap the icon and it takes about 10 secs to even open the loading screen. It's mainly with a slow internet connection, but I would think the loading screen would come up first.

The app isn't in the store yet, it's just on my phone through the simulator, would this cause any issues? It only happens after it's been sent to the background and then re-activated.

Any ideas, sorry to be a little vague?

I'm not getting any errors and I don't have any code in the AppDelegate file.

Comment: If you suspect a slow internet connection: do you do your networking on a background thread?

Comment: I actually found this was happening on all apps I have that aren't released through the app store. Also it happens only when going from a good mobile connection to a poor one, when wireless is off.

Comment: Do you the network link conditioner turned on? Though I would suspect that it affects all apps (Settings -> Developer -> Status (under Network Link Conditioner). Make sure it's turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it in instrument. There must be memory leaks.

Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been playing with that and the Activity Monitor looks good releasing back down going back and forth through parts of the app. The allocation grows slightly as I'm clicking through table view detail pages. Nothing increases when the app is in the background.

Comment: I'm on my real device. I did open the Leaks instrument and I do get a leak popping up most of the time when selecting a tableview going to the detail page. It's hard to make sense of the retain/Release and 0x... output is though.

Comment: It shows the leaks in the foundation library
+0x8c bl                  "CFStringCreateWithBytes"
+0x90 cbz                 x0, "-[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]+0xa8"

Comment: Do you have any String Variable??

Comment: Dear, It's very little error So, It'll be hard to identify if you are in startup stage of project try to build new one.. Or if you are ahead of this re build your modules one by one and when you get the error change current class..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116285/discussion-between-user3712837-and-jack).